# Octave index out of bounds

Tags: octave, gradient-descent

The program is an optimized gradient descent.

Here is the code :

```
    clear all
    close all
    [x,y] = meshgrid(-2:0.1:2);                                            
   z = x.^2 + 100*y.^2;                                          
   n = 1;
   k(n)=0.01;
   arret = 0.0001;                                                         
   mesh(x,y,z);                                                            
   [x1(n),y1(n)] = ginput(1);                                             
   diff_x(n) = 2*x1(n);                                                   
   diff_y(n) = 200*y1(n);                                                 
   while sqrt(diff_x(n)^2 + diff_y(n)^2) > arret && n < 30
     k(n) = sqrt(diff_x(n)^2 + diff_y(n)^2)/(8*x1(n).^2+2*10.^6*y1(n).^2);         
     x1(n+1) = x1(n) - k(n)*diff_x(n);                                    
     y1(n+1) = y1(n) - k(n)*diff_y(n);    
     n = n+1;  
     diff_x(n) = 2*x1(n);
     diff_y(n) = 200*y1(n);
     z1(n) = x1(n).^2 + 100*y1(n).^2;                                     
     plot3(x1(n),y1(n),z1(n));                                             
   end

   x1(n)
   y1(n)
   n
```

So I got this and I don't understand why.

> error: GradientPasOptFinal2: A(I): index out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1
>
> error: called from:
>
> error:   error:   C:\Octave\octave-3.8.2\GradientPasOptFinal2.m at line 13, column 8

**SOLVED** : the k(n) between y1(n) and n was the reason, i don't know why, but now the program works, thank you !

Comment: Thank you Doelleri for the correction, i wrote it quickly and english isn't my native language...

Answer (score 0):

You have only defined k(1). k(2) is undefined.
Move this line:

```
k(n) = sqrt(diff_x(n)^2 + diff_y(n)^2)/(8*x1(n).^2+2*10.^6*y1(n).^2);
```

Ahead of these lines:

```
x1(n+1) = x1(n) - k(n)*diff_x(n);                                    
y1(n+1) = y1(n) - k(n)*diff_y(n);
```

And it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, i'm a novice on Octave, but x1(n) and y1(n) need a value of k(n), on the other side, k(n) needs the values of x1(n) and y1(n).

other edit : in the while, does the computer understand that he has k(n) = 0.01, so he can calculate x1(n+1) and y1(n+1), then he can calculate k(n+1), then x1(n+2) and y1(n+2) ....

i don't understand the problem.

Comment: I'm still stuck, i tried many things it doesn't work, i don't know what to do.

Comment: Thank for your time, i tried it, it doesn't work.랬error: GradientPasOptFinal2: A(I): index out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1
error: called from:
error:   C:\Octave\octave-3.8.2\GradientPasOptFinal2.m at line 13, column 8

I've just no idea to fix it, line 13 column 8 it's diff_x(n), all is defined, it's very strange ...

Comment: now i have it :
error:   C:\Octave\octave-3.8.2\GradientPasOptFinal2.m at line 25, column 1
error: GradientPasOptFinal2: A(I): index out of bounds; value 10 out of bound 9